# How to resolve `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 1` for SNN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, loss

What is a loss function in PyTorch that will allow me to calculate the loss for a multi-target problem? I have three target variables. I saw a suggestion for `BCEWithLogitsLoss()` but it produces this error:

`RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 1`

I am working on a spiking neural network as well. The `RunTimeError` above is thrown at `acc = np.mean((targets == idx).detach().cpu().numpy())`. I don't actually this this is a matter of the loss function, but rather a function I have to print the batch accuracy:

```
def print_batch_accuracy(data, targets, train = False):
    output, _ = net(data.view(batch_size, -1))
    _, idx = output.sum(dim = 0).max(1)
    print(targets)
    acc = np.mean((targets == idx).detach().cpu().numpy())

    if train:
        print(f"Train set accuracy for a single minibatch: {acc * 100:.2f}%")
    else:
        print(f"Test set accuracy for a single minibatch: {acc * 100:.2f}%")
```

The shape of my batch is `torch.Size([25, 128, 3])` of type `Float`.

Comment: is your `target` indexes of labels? can you paste your `target` as well

Answer (score 0):

The error is a result of the accuracy printer function not being designed for multi-target classification. I am guessing your target tensor's first dimension corresponds to the total number of correct classes (3), whereas the function is expecting the first dim to be batch size (128).

The function `_, idx = output.sum(dim = 0).max(1)` is returning the neuron with the largest number of spikes. This is then checked against targets `(targets == idx)`, which implies accuracy is being measured for a single-target problem. This should be modified to check against all possible correct classes.

As for your question about suitable loss functions, `BCEWithLogitsLoss()` could be applied to the accumulated output spikes and that would work well.

Alternatively, each output neuron may have a target spike count which is compared against the actual spike count using `MSELoss()`.